# smallest positive integer with specified remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a way to find the smallest positive integer, whose remainders when divided by a list of prime numbers have been specified?

Comment: Yes.  Study the chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chinese Remainder Theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

There are a few different ways to actually find the desired value.  What works best often depends on what moduli (divisors) you are working with.

Comment: Unfortunately Wikipedia is banned here in Turkey, but from my understanding, the chinese remainder is an existence theorem, not a theorem that gives the smallest positive integer. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Some proofs are constructive (i.e., suggest an actual algorithm).  Depending on the primes in question different methods may be easier or harder to apply.  Can you google Chinese Remainder Theorem in your area?  There should be other helpful websites.

Comment: See:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKMYNKbFHBE

Answer (score 1):

Chinese remainder theorem.

Rough idea:

Let $N$ have remainder $r_1$ when divided by $p_1$ and remainder $r_2$ when divided by $p_2$.

I claim that so long as $p_1$ and $p_2$ have no factors in common (which they don't; they are prime) I can find an $M = r_1 + p_2*a = r_2 + p_1*b$ where $0 \le a < p_1$ and $0 \le b < p_2$.

The $M$ is therefore the smallest number with those remainders for $p_1$ and $p_2$.

As $p_3$ will have no factors in common with $p_1p_2$ I can bootstrap and find a $K = r_3 + p_1p_2*a = M + p_3*b$.  And repeat for each prime and remainder to get a final result.

So to prove the claim:

$M = r_1 + p_2*a = r_2 + p_1*b$ $\iff $ $s= r_2 - r_1 = p_2*a - p_3*b$.

As $\gcd(p_2, p_3) = 1$ and $1|s$, that there are integer solutions are what is called Euclid's lemma.

Basically .... you know it's easiest to just show an example.

Let's solve $N$ has remainders $2,5,7$ when divided by $5,7, $ and $11$ (I actually have no idea what the solution is when I picked those... we will find out together.)

So to solve $M = 2 + 5a = 5+7b$:

$5-2 = 3 = 5a - 7b$.

We have $7$ and $5$.

$7 = 1*5 + 2$ so $2 = 7- 1*5$

$5 = 2*2 + 1$ so $1 = 5- 2*2 = 5-2(7-1*5)= 3*5 - 2*7$

So $3 = 9*5 - 6*7$

So $5 - 2 = 9*5 - 6*7$

So $M = 2+ 9*5 = 5+6*7 = 47$ is has remainder $2$ and $5$ when divided by $5$ and $7$ but it clearly is the smallest such number because $47 > 5*7 = 35$ so $47-5*7 = 12$ will also have remainders $2$ and $5$ when divided by $5$ and $7$.

So now we want to solve $N = 7 + 11*a = 12 + 5*7*b$.

So $12 - 7 = 5 = 11a - 35b$

So ... $35 = 3*11 + 2$ so $2 = 35 - 3*11$.

$11 = 5*2 + 1$ so $1 = 11 - 5*2 = 11 - 5(35- 3*11) = 16*11 - 5*35$

So $5 =12 - 7= 80*11 - 25*35$ and

$K = 7 + 80*11 = 12 + 25*35 = 887$ has the remainders we want.

But $887 > 35*11 = 385$  so it isn't the smallest.  But $887 - 2*385 = 117$ will be the smallest number with the desired remainders.

Euclid's Algorithm for solving $m = ap_1 - bp_2$ so long as $\gcd(p_1, p_2)|m$ will always work because we get smaller and small equations based on linear combinations of $p_1, p_2$. As thes equations will always have $\gcd(p_1,p_2)$ as factors, and as we can always get small and smaller equations. Eventually it will reduce to $\gcd(p_1,p_2)= c*x - d*y$ where $c$ and $d$ where derived from a string of linear combinations of $p_1, p_2$.

I realize it's not a proof but I hope it is clear by induction that it must always end with such a result.